# TypeScript: create new instance of a class give me undefine

Tags: node.js, typescript

i´m migrating my node.js app to typescript and is the first time for me doing this, for some reason after declare and create my class when i create a new instance of the class instance of my class controller get this error after making the request to the end point:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'utilities' of undefined
    at getCategories (C:\Users\Migue\Desktop\movie-arcade-backend\src\controllers\categories.controller.ts:19:34)
```

**Utilities**

```
export default class Utilities {
  constructor() {}

  mapFavorities(favorites: Movie[]) {
    if (!favorites || favorites.length === 0) {
      return [];
    }
    return favorites.map((f) => {
      return {
        _id: f._id,
        new: f.new,
        rate: f.rate,
        content_type: f.content_type,
        name: f.name,
        cover: f.cover,
        release_date: f.release_date,
        created: f.created,
        updateOn: f.updateOn,
        item_type: f.item_type,
        comments: f.comments,
      };
    });
  }

  mapPageParams(req: Request) {
    const params: any = {};
    Object.keys(req.query).forEach((key) => {
      params[`${key}`] = req.query[`${key}`] === 'undefined' ? undefined : req.query[`${key}`];
    });
    if (params.sortBy) {
      params['sort'] = {
        [`${params.sortBy}`]: `${params.direction}`,
      };
    }
    return params;
  }

  isValidToken(req: Request) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    if (token) {
      try {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  isAuthenticated(req: Request) {
    return !!req.headers.authorization && !!req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }

  decodeToken(req: Request) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    try {
      return this.isAuthenticated(req) && this.isValidToken(req) ? jwt.decode(token) : undefined;
    } catch (error) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  getRole(req: Request) {
    const userToken: any = this.decodeToken(req);
    return userToken ? userToken.auth_rol : undefined;
  }
  generateImgPath(req: Request, imgFile?: any) {
    return `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${imgFile ? imgFile.filename : req.file.filename}`;
  }

  getImageName(image: string) {
    return image.split('images/')[1];
  }

  fileExist(file: string) {
    return fs.existsSync(`./images/${file}`);
  }

  deleteFileFromFs(file: string) {
    fs.unlinkSync(`./images/${file}`);
  }
}
```

**category.controller**

```
import Utilities from '../utilities/utilities';

export default class CategoryController {
  private readonly utilities: Utilities = new Utilities();
  private readonly movieAdapter: MovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter();
  private readonly categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter();
  constructor() {}

  getCategories(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const pageQueryParams = this.utilities.mapPageParams(req);
    if (pageQueryParams.page) {
      Category.countDocuments({}, (error, count) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        from(
          Category.find()
            .skip(+pageQueryParams.pageSize * +pageQueryParams.page - +pageQueryParams.pageSize)
            .limit(+pageQueryParams.pageSize)
            .sort(pageQueryParams.sort)
        ).subscribe(
          (list) => {
            res.status(200).send({ count, list });
          },
          (error) => {
            res.send(error);
          }
        );
      });
    } else {
      from(Category.find()).subscribe(
        (list) => {
          res.status(200).send(list);
        },
        (error) => {
          res.status(500).send(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

**routes**

```
export const router = express.Router();
const authMiddleWare = new AuthMiddleWare();
const categoryController = new CategoryController();

/* Get all the categories */
router.get('/', categoryController.getCategories);

/* Get single Category */
router.get('/:id', authMiddleWare.checkAuth, authMiddleWare.checkRole, categoryController.getSingleCategory);

/* Create a new category */
router.post('/', authMiddleWare.checkAuth, authMiddleWare.checkRole, categoryController.createCategory);

/* Update a category */
router.put('/:id', authMiddleWare.checkAuth, authMiddleWare.checkRole, categoryController.updateCategory);

/* Delete a category */
router.delete('/:id', authMiddleWare.checkAuth, authMiddleWare.checkRole, categoryController.removeCategory);

/* Get items by category */
router.get('/category/:name', categoryController.getItemsByCategory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `this` is `undefined` since you're passing a reference to the `categoryController.getCategories` function and not the class context itself. Instead do this:

router.get('/', categoryController.getCategories.bind(categoryController);

Alternatively you can bind `getCategories` within the `CategoryController` constructor.

Comment: Yeap that was the solution thanks so much, just one small question, how can i refactor my class to dont have to use bind...?

Comment: Found the way to do it, thanks for the answer : )